# resize image to fit in col-xs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to resize an image to fit win within these parameters but if I use img-responsive its too small? I just need it to be a fixed size or adjust to the screen resolution if possible?

```
<div class="container-fluid f2p-nav hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><img class="image-container-center img-responsive" src="images/f2p6.png" alt="Chania"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css is :

```
.image-container-center {
  margin-top:27px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg611xr3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to resize an image in order to fit into a certain column in bootstrap you just need to use a unit percentage in setting an image size for example in width, height, max-width or min-width. Here's the following code. I hope this will help you.

```
<div class="col-xs-4"><img class="image-container-center img-responsive" src="images/f2p6.png" alt="Chania" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```